# Xcode instruments low memory warning app killed on 2 MB live bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app crashes with low memory warning on device, even though the max live bytes in instruments is 3 MB tops. I do use a lot heavy PNG's in my app(in about 20 ViewControllers) ,  I believe ARC should've taken care of it.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Live Bytes are not the whole story.  Keep track of your app's dirty memory (There are lots of tutorials if you search for dirty memory in instruments, etc)

Comment: Also, check for Memory Leaks in your app.

Comment: Yes I did run static analyse and memory leaks, no issues so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. The problem was that I was doing animation using a bunch of PNG's.

So when using this

```
image.animationImages=imageFrames;
```

it was caching all the images in memory each time it was called, which led to dirty memory filling up and crashing the application. So, after using it each time to release the image cache we need to do this

```
image.animationImages=nil;
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it helped you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce size of heavy png files. Png file must be good in resolution but size must be less not more than 2 MB.I also had the same problem but used Three 20 Framework which solved my issue because it manages Images files allocation perfectly. Now a days it seem Three 20 is not getting updated but still you can try it in a sample app if you want . Here is the link :http://three20.info/

Comment: Nobody should be using three20 nowadays.